# How to specify terminal resolution?

Tags: 22.04, display, intel-graphics, display-resolution

Setup:

- Ubuntu Server 22.02 (no GUI)
- Desktop with an old Intel CPU (3rd gen I think) that only goes up to 1080p
- 4K TV

This server is typically headless. I do not have another monitor in the house.

The issue I'm experiencing is that for some reason, the CLI is configured to run at 4k, but it's outputting at 1080p. The result is what you see in the attached image after running `apt upgrade`.
[image: Image too big for TV].

I'm not sure if during boot Ubuntu is detecting the TV as 4k incorrectly? My TV (LG CX) says the computer is booting up at an unsupported resolution so I don't see anything until I see the OS bootup text scrolling through.

Everything I'm reading online about this keeps referring to xrandr, but that command isn't available (I think it's only there if I have a GUI installed). I've also seen details about a monitors.xml - that file doesn't exist.

There are no dedicated graphics cards on this server. Just the built in Intel stuff.

As a solution, I would like the terminal to either respect the 1080p resolution, or to output at 4k instead of 1080p, whichever works (I don't care about 30hz - as mentioned this is typically a headless server with only CLI). I can currently SSH into it just fine but in this instance I need to use the device physically.

Answer (score 0):

In the file `/etc/default/grub` you can configure boot options.

To disable graphics, uncomment (delete the leading # character):

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

or change resolution:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600
```

Save and apply with the command `update-grub`.